# Separate pages from PDF into images or HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

For a project i need to create a webtool where users can upload PDF documents that can be displayed in  a browser with some page flip jQuery stuff.

In order to do so, I need to separate the PDF into pages (images or html) to generate the jQuery flipbook.

Anyone got suggestions how to do such a thing?

Comment: Please post your research efforts and any code you've come up with so far

Comment: Did you try with GhostScript? If you have any problem with it you may come back with a specific question...

Comment: Look into [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: I have been exploring the possibilities of GhostScript, I was wondering if there was a working concept I could examine

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/heiglandreas/Org_Heigl_Ghostscript for a PHP-wrapper to ghostscript.

Answer (score 1):

You need [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) to perform that. Once installed you need to upload the PDF and perform something like this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

$im = new imagick();
$im->setresolution(300, 300); // For hi-res
$im->readimage($uploadfile . "[0]"); // [0] is the PDF page
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->writeimage($newname);

}
```

You will have the PNG file of the page 1 on $newname.

EDIT:

If you need to know how pages the PDF have, you could perform this:

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->pingimage($uploadfile);
$pages = $im->getnumberimages();
```

And then run it with a for loop and save the pages.

Comment: Fix the extra `"` (`$im->writeimage($newname");`)

Comment: Actually you need Ghostscript to convert your  PDF to images. Imagemagik does nothing else than to delegate the rendering process to an undrlying ghostscript. If you want to do some image manipulation also Imagemagic is the way to go.